# My laravel API only returns empty curly bracket

Tags: php, api, postman, laravel-9

This is the response I get when making a get request to my API

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvgP2.png)

The code below is my current code

```
function getDNSData(string $domain)
{
    $dns = new Dns();

    try {
        $records = json_encode($dns->getRecords($domain));
        return $records;
    } catch(CouldNotFetchDns $e) {
        dd($e);
        return ["errors" => $e];
    }
}
```

I used die dump function to check if data was being passed through correctly and that worked
Using json_decode i couldnt get it to work either

[diedumpResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9QEa.png)

[image: The print_r results]

Comment: Do a more useful `dd($dns->getRecords($domain));` to check what `$dns->getRecords($domain)` is returning

Comment: I already tried that and it returns the things i expected Do you want to see what it returns?

Comment: Yes, that might help

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9QEa.png
Thats what my dd returns

Comment: Could you try a `print_r($dns->getRecords($domain));` so we can see some of the data please

Comment: Looks to me like json_encode might not be able to create a serialized representation of those Spatie\Dns\Records instances ...?

Comment: I added the print_r results

Comment: Update code as below and check:
```PHP

$records = $dns->getRecords($domain);
return json_encode($records[0] ?? "");
```

Comment: When i updated my code to that I got ```{}``` as a result